# Bluej basics - tester class

Tags: oop

I got some troubles making a method that transfer money from object to another 
which is mainly was to make a class that simulates a tester class that do the following

```
public class BankAccountTest
     {
     public void main()
     {
     // Create an account with an opening balance of 5000 AED for Mr. Said
     BankAccount acc1 = new BankAccount("Said", 5000);
     acc1.withdraw(1000);
     acc1.printAccountInfo(); // Should display on the screen: "Said's blanace is 4000"
    // Create an accoutn with an initial balance of ZERO for Mr. Shady
     BankAccount acc2 = new BankAccount("Shady");
     acc2.deposit(2000);

    // Transfer 3000 from acc2 to acc1. If successful, the method returns 0, otherwise -1
     int code = acc2.transfer(acc1, 3000);
     if(code !=0) {
     System.out.println("Insufficient Fund!");
     }

    System.our.println(acc1.balance() );
     System.our.println(acc2.balance() );
     }
     }
```

So here is my code

```
public class BankAccount
    {
      public int balance;
      private int deposite;
      private int withdraw;
      private String name;


        public BankAccount(String name)
        { balance = 5000;

      }
       public BankAccount(String nameName, int balance)
       {
         name = nameName;
         this.balance = balance;
         deposite = 0;
         withdraw = 0;
        }
       public void DepostieMoney (int deposite)
       { this.balance = balance + deposite;}
       public void WithdrawMoney(int withdraw)
       { this.balance = balance - withdraw;

       }
       public void printAccountInfo()
       {
        System.out.println(this.name + "'s balance is " + balance);
       }
       public void TransferMoney(BankAccount that , int balance)
       { this.balance= this.balance - balance;

    }  
        }
```

what I couldn't able to figure is how to make the following method transfer the items of the first object to the second object

```
public void TransferMoney(BankAccount that , int balance)
   { this.balance= this.balance - balance;
```

So how actually I can specify methods for specific object ?.

> edited withdrawMoney method

```
public void withdrawMoney(int balance)
    {if ( balance <= this.balance)
     this.balance = this.balance - balance;
     else
     {System.out.println("insfufficient funds");} 
    }
```

Comment: After several tests I just found there's something wrong with the transferMoney method which's if the transferred amount is more than the balance, the transaction will not be cancelled, it actually does what's mentioned on the withdrawMoney but the problem here is the other account received the transferred money which shouldn't happen

Comment: You're completely right here, withdraw should check if there is enough money and return boolean value of success status.  The deposite should not be called if withdraw has failed. I'll update the transfer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the Java coding style suggests:

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
>   lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized (e.g run(); runFast();  getBackground(); )

Now, for you question, you're trying to transfer the money from the one account to the other, so the method called on one object should call the second object in order to complete the transaction.

```
public void transferMoney(BankAccount that , int balance)
   { 
     //sanity check here
     if (this == that || that == null)
         return;

      If (withdrawMoney(balance)) {
          that.depositeMoney(balance);
      }
   }
```

As you see I choose not to use the variables directly but through the methods. The reason is that the logic around the method could be more than simply updating the variable, for example you may want to print the action. This way you only need to update once the code in your method, the transferMoney method will remain the same.